# Set title and image for now play audio in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

How do I set the title and image of now playing audio in background using the `AVPlayer`?

My code so far:

```
  let path: String = String(format: "pathtoaudio")
    let aPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
    let anAudioStreamer: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: aPlayerItem)
    player = anAudioStreamer
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    let nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : "Artist!",  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : "Title!", MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork : MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(named: "nour.jpg")!)]
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

I am trying to use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` but am not seeing the information on the lock screen.

Answer (score 4):

Your Title and Artist keys look correct, but to set the album artwork you need to use the [`MPMediaItemArtwork`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItemArtwork_ClassReference/index.html) object:

```
let nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : "Artist!",  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : "Title!", MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork : MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(...))]
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
```

You may also need to explicitly subscribe to remote control events as well:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Comment: I did that , also I am not seeing the information in the lock screen , please check my code edit above

Comment: Well, tried this, and it simply doesn't work for me. No trace on the iOS (or AppleTV I'm casting to) UI. However- when I start casting, there is a transient message on the AppleTV screen, with the URL of the item I'm playing. Apple documentation on the subject is horrible, to non-existent, and this answer only added new agony...